# Functional equation for cosine on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, functional-equations

This was part of last week's homework assignment in my Clac 1 class:

Let $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$ be continuous,
$$f(\frac{\pi}{2})=0 \hspace{2mm} \textrm{and} \hspace{2mm} f(x+y)= f(x)f(y)-\sqrt{1-f(x)^2}\sqrt{1-f(y)^2}$$

Show that $f$ is uniquely determined and well-defined.

I tried proving this by first showing that $f(\frac{x}{2})$ , $f(\frac{x}{2^k})$ and in turn $f(\frac{\pi}{2^k})$ and $f(\frac{j\hspace{1mm}\pi}{2^k})$ are uniquely determined. From that I can also see that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$ and since $f$ is continuous $f(x)=1$. After this I appear to be stuck tho.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated, keep in mind that I am not allowed to use any advanced (anything beyond 1st semester) theorems.

Comment: What elementary function do you know that have $f(0) = 1$ and $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$? Only one comes to mind for me, and it definitely has the second property.

Comment: You seem to be aware that $f(x) = \cos x$ works. You determined all the values $f(\frac{j \pi}{2^k})$, how many continuous $f$ with these values in these points can be?